# can the term "is when" be used in grammatically correct wtriting?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to learn whether using the phrase "is when" ever grammatically correct in writing.

Comment: Noon is when the big hand and the little hand are on twelve; unless of course it's night-time,

Comment: or noon "is when" the sun is directly overhead.

Comment: @user125675 You can find these two words together as mentionned in other commenbts, but you need to add context if you want a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Those two words following each other would be grammatically correct if in a sentence where "when" is a conjunction introducing an adjective clause.

The verb "is" is a linking verb, so what follows must be a predicate nominative or predicate adjective. The word "when" would only be correct following "is" as a conjunction, and since it is used to describe at what time something would take place, it would be a conjunction introducing an adjective clause.

Example: "Eight o'clock is when the last train leaves."

I don't think it would be correct to call it a phrase though.